# geom_hline will not show up whereas it did before

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get 2 horizontal dashed lines at y-int 150 and 300 to show up on my plot(s). They were showing up before, and I'm not sure what I did but they are no longer showing up. I did not mess with the code chunk itself so I wonder if I deleted/altered a df/package that the plot was dependent on.

```
# Create labels and limits for week numbers
labels_week_n <- c("W\n1", "W\n2", "W\n3", "W\n4", "W\n5")
limits_week_n <- c(
  "Week 15 of 2016", "Week 16 of 2016", "Week 17 of 2016",
  "Week 18 of 2016", "Week 19 of 2016"
)
# Weekly_moderate_very plot
# for all 33 participants
weekly_moderate_very_p <- 
  weekly_data %>%
  {
    ggplot(.) +
      geom_line(
        aes(
          x = as.factor(week_number), 
          y = weekly_mod_very_m,
          group = id, 
          color = as.factor(id)
          ),
        linejoin = "mitre",
        show.legend = FALSE,
        size = .5
        ) +
      geom_point(
        aes(
          x = as.factor(week_number), 
          y = weekly_mod_very_m, 
          group = id, 
          color = as.factor(id)
          ), 
        show.legend = FALSE, 
        size = 1) +
      labs(
        title = "Moderate/vigorous activity",
        subtitle = "Weekly totals for 33 participants",
        y = "Minutes"
      ) +
      scale_x_discrete(
        name = NULL,
        limits = limits_week_n,
        labels = labels_week_n,
        expand = c(0, 0)
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(
        breaks = c(0, 150, 300, 450, 600, 750, 900), 
        limits = c(0, 1060)
        ) +
      scale_color_discrete() +
      theme_minimal() +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 150, linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 300, linetype = "dashed") +
      facet_wrap(~id, drop = TRUE, nrow = 3, ncol = 11, scales = "fixed") +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(
          margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 0),
          size = 14,
          hjust = 1,
          face = "bold"
        ),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(
          margin = margin(1, 5, 5, 0),
          size = 10,
          hjust = 1,
          face = "italic"
        ),
        axis.title.y = element_text(
          margin = margin(0, 5, 0, 5),
          size = 12
        ),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(.75, "lines")
      )
  }
weekly_moderate_very_p
```

This yields the following
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mZHq.png)

It used to look like this, and that's what I would like it to look like again:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOgIE.png)

I tried removing/changing the linetype with no results, beyond that I'm kind of at a loss.

**SOLVED** Thanks all, I feel so silly for not thinking to define the line color!

Comment: have you tried changing the color argument in `geom_hline`, e.g., `geom_hline(yintercept = 150, linetype = "dashed", color = "black")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your code without `weekly_data`. Here is what I would try:

The hline is there, just not very visible. Changing size and color could solve the issue.

```
geom_hline(yintercept = 150, linetype = "dashed", size = 2, color = "black") +
geom_hline(yintercept = 300, linetype = "dashed", size = 2, color = "black")
```

or use `linewidth = 2` if `size` is not accepted